# Server-side pagination and filtering with react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to implement server-side filtering in a table. Server-side pagination is already implemented. The table is a child component. The page component has a filter and a function that is called in the usa Effect of the table component. If I pass query parameters to the fetchData function, the query goes with the same page I was on.  can't find the answer, help me out please.  Link to Code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-dan-80c7et?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: just pagination only, i saw this in net https://codesandbox.io/s/server-side-pagination-react-table-query-demo-js-9wn8h?file=/src/PokemonTable.js:973-985

Comment: only pagination works, but it's not friends with search. I still can't fix it

Comment: check last few stars, those have serverside pagination,filter https://github.com/jose2007kj?tab=stars

Comment: your link is working, both server-side pagination & filtering. pls check

Comment: if you make a filter request not from the first page, then 2 requests are executed: first it goes with the page we are on now, then it immediately resets to the first one. In the tools you can see the error